# styling divs with jquery ui title

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

Is there any way i can style a regular div container with the styling applied to jquery dialogs. I basically want to have a div panel with some text content but with title bar styling just like the jquery ui dialog boxes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well from my understanding the jQuery UI Dialog is something like:

```
<div> main container
    <div></div> title area
    <div></div> content area
</div>
```

So you could simply have that structure and apply the appropriate styles?

Here is a [lazily plagiarized version](http://jsfiddle.net/DpCY3/1/) from copying some of the styles from the default  dialogue.